# Como crear un acceso directo anclado personalizado?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Mi duda o problema actual es que quiero poder crear un acceso directo en pantalla (actualmente como pude observar en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts) se llama acceso anclado) que le permita al usuario activar una grabadora de voz con solo pisar o arrastrar el icono (acceso directo) que se encontrara en uno de los lados de la pantalla sin necesidad de acceder directamente a mi aplicación, un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr es el de el limpiador 

[DU Speed Booster & Optimizador](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay&hl=es) el cual trae una función llamada optimizacion de un toque desde un icono de nave espacial que arrastras hacia al centro de la pantalla y sale dispara con una animación. Esto mismo es lo que yo quiero lograr, pero en vez de una nave espacial voladora sera un icono de un micrófono (esto es lo que me refiero con personalizado).

Me disculpo por no presentar ni una pizca de código es que no conozco mucho referente a este tema y lo único que tengo hasta ahora es lo que ofrece la documentación. Si tienes una idea, sugerencia o corrección por favor decírmela.

Gracias y espero su ayuda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si no lo entiendo mal lo que buscas es un elemento flotante que los puedas mover por la pantalla.

Te dejo un tutorial [Android Floating Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20220529011733/https://www.journaldev.com/14673/android-floating-widget)

[image: Android Floating Widget]
<sub>(fuente: [journaldev.com](https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/android-floating-widget-output-1.gif))</sub>

O bien si solo quieres que el elemento sea flotante en tu aplicación, puedes utilizar el sisguiente componente [Assertive-touch](https://github.com/mmoamenn/Assertive-Touch)

Muy fácil de implementar y customizar

```
public class DemoApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    
    ATButton.setup(this) ;
    ATButton.getInstance().setTargetClass(HelpActivity.class);
    ATButton.getInstance().setIcon(R.drawable.help);
    ATButton.getInstance().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  }
```

[image: Assertive-touch]